# 2nd removeChild does not function?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm not sure why the 2nd removeChild is not functioning, both DOM elements have the same indexing but it only removes it from partylist not bride select. I'm newer to JS any help would be gratefully appreciated!

```
function removeOption() {
    var party = document.getElementById('partylist');
    var bride = document.getElementById('bride');
    var mem = party.options[party.selectedIndex];
    var obj1 = party.removeChild(party.options[party.selectedIndex]);
    var obj2 = bride.removeChild(bride.options[party.selectedIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Can you throw in your relevant DOM as well?

Comment: Likely because `party.selectedIndex` changes after you removed that option (`party.options[party.selectedIndex]`). Put a `console.log(party.selectedIndex)` between the remove calls.

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML.  In fact, even better to build a demo in jsFiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t94a26pb/ is the jsfiddle for it, but on this the boxes don't work at all...i don't get that

Comment: @MatthewWalker: You haven't configured the fiddle correctly. You have to configure it to include the JS code in the head or body. If you fix that and did what I suggested then you will notice that `party.selectedIndex` is `-1` after you removed the option.

Comment: Follow up from @FelixKling, also try setting `partyIndex` as a variable before the `var obj1` statement then using that variable directly in `party.removeChild(party.options[partyIndex])` and `bride.removeChild(bride.options[partyIndex])`.

Comment: Thanks for that, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/t94a26pb/1/ fixed up

Comment: i tried that as well but to no avail
`function removeOption() {
 var party = document.getElementById('partylist');
 var bride = document.getElementById('bride');
 var mem = party.options[party.selectedIndex];
 var obj1 = party.removeChild(party.options[mem]);
 var obj2 = bride.removeChild(bride.options[mem]);
}`

Answer (score 0):

After you removed the option from `party`, `party.selectedIndex` is `-1`. Because the selected option doesn't exist anymore, nothing is selected. You can verify this by adding `console.log(party.selectedIndex)` between the remove statements.

`bride.options[-1]` returns `undefined` of course, so nothing is removed from `bride`.

The simplest solution is to swap the two statements:

```
var obj2 = bride.removeChild(bride.options[party.selectedIndex]);
var obj1 = party.removeChild(party.options[party.selectedIndex]);
```

---

I highly recommend to learn [how to debug JavaScript code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/?hl=en), so that you can solve such issues on your own.

Comment: @Matthew: Don't forget to mark the question as solved by accepting this answer (by clicking on the checkmark outline next to it).